# Angular AWS blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cors

I created an AWS API Gateway that access a Lambda Function.

If I try to call the Gateway from Postman everything works fine. But when I try to call the get API with my Angular Application I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'apiUrl' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I create my Angular Request with the following code:

```js
let params = new HttpParams().set('username','test@mail.com').append('password','1234');
this.http.get(apiUrl, { params }).subscribe(
  res => { alert('success'); },
  err => { alert('fail'); }
)
```

I already enabled the CORS in my API Gateway.
I hope you guys can help me to call my AWS API.

My current option method looks like this:
[Integration Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj0Eg.png)

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You are forming your request correctly in Angular.
The problem has nothing to do with the client side of your app, and everything to do with the way you set up CORS support in AWS.

Postman accesses your API ok because Postman does not enforce the "same-origin" policy that the web browser does, i.e. it bypasses CORS entirely.

For a browser to successfully make the request, the API must respond to an OPTIONS request on the same endpoint with a 200 return code, and include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on that response, either indicating the actual origin of the request or the wildcard '*'.

AWS's documentation on this is quite clear and extensive.

Comment: Hi I already added the Options to the endpoint and included the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the header (screenshot in the question)

Comment: If the "extensive" AWS documentation on this were even remotely clear, there would not be as many people having the same problem as I see all over the Internet, from AWS's own forums to just about anywhere. If https://stackoverflow.com/users/982341/greybeardedgeek has a specific clear explanation on AWS documentation, can he please reference it. I found nothing clear there at all. It may be easier using the CLI, but I find the graphic user interface of API Gateway confusing at best.

Comment: @greybeardedgeek Can you mention the document link here ?

Comment: The AWS API Gateway Documentation for CORS configuration is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to send a response from your API(server side), this response need to include:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
```

Here's an example of how to send a Response via Lambda(.js):

```js
function buildResponse(statusCode, body) {
  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}
```

Just add this to your Lambda code and call it when you return a response.

Hint: statusCode could be 200, and body is your "response".

Answer (score 2):

Your code in Angular is ok.

> let params = new
> HttpParams().set('username','test@mail.com').append('password','1234');
> this.http.get(apiUrl, {params}).subscribe(
> res => {alert('success');},
> err => {alert('fail');}
> )

An error occurred while sending the header.

1. In the AWS API Gateway for the desired API, the `Resources` tab is selected in the menu on the left.
2. The `GET` method is selected
3. In the `Actions` drop-down menu, click on `Enable CORS`.
   [image]
4. In the field for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, at the very end, and before `'`, separate with a comma and add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
5. In the field below, for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be entered `'*'`
6. Configure settings with the `Enable CORS and replace existing CORS headers` button
   [image]

Also, add a header to `GET` -> `Integration Request` -> `HTTP Headers`. `name` is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Mapped from` is `'*'`


As well check headers in Postmen. For testing.

Comment: I have added everything as you suggested, neither CORS is resolved nor seeing the headers in postman. but response comes with 200 status code only in postman. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In API Gateway, under Resources-->Actions. The Actions dropdown has option to enable CORS. Check if CORS are enabled and you are allowing all origin.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old issue, but i'm facing this right now. My hint is to look at you Options method on browser console, check if you got an error on this. In my case, i'm wrongly set authorization at OPTIONS method and when its return a 401 OPTIONS mocked method doesn't have a 401 response configured, with cors required headers, so you need to check why options are return error, or configure a Options response with required headers on erro too.